# Retrieve new data added under child in firebase java

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Trying at this moment just print "child" when a new child is added under a given category.
The end goal is to print the value of the new child added so let's say my device adds a new temperature value under 'data/temperature'

```
    public static void startListeners(){
        DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/data/temperature");
        ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    System.out.println(child);
                }
            }

            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                    .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.create(null))
                    .setDatabaseUrl(DATABASE_URL)
                    .build();
            FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        while(true) {
            try {
                startListeners();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Data: 
[image: Data structure]

Comment: Seems you need a serviceaccount no matter what, was my issue.

Comment: You are trying to print a DataSnapshot object! Use getValue to retrieve the value from the DataSnapshot object. For example, you can use int h = child.child("Humidity").getValue(Integer.class); and int t = child.child("Temperature").getValue(Integer.class); Or you can create your own class that has a temperature and humidity properties and use it. I would strongly recommend reading the documentation, it is really easy and could save you a lot of time. https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write

Comment: Hey, I sorted it with service account. The code worked as I wanted it.